# extjs 4 create multiple records using form data and combobox

Tags: extjs4, sencha-architect

I am just not able to understand what I m doing wrong here.
I am trying to add multiple records in json store using multiple IDs passed by comobox

var f = this.getPanel();
    var form = f.getForm();

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('aStore');

var cc = form.findField('classSel');
var vv = cc.getValue();

var arrayLength = vv.length;
    for (var n = 0; n < arrayLength; n++)
    {
    var gg = form.findField('ClassID');
    var mm = gg.getValue();
    var ee = gg.setValue(vv[n]);
    var nn = gg.getValue();
    var formData = form.getValues();
        var sss = store.add(formData);
  }
f.close();
```

It sends data to mysql many to many table using php. Everything is working fine. Except that my loop is creating multiple entries for each ID. I understand combobox getValue() gives value in loop
than  am iterating over loop values. Somehow it creates more than required 'post' request. Please please please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the entire form's values and creating/adding a new record(model) to the store every time through the loop. This will trigger a new POST because, I assume, you have autoSync set to true on your store.